# Form doesn't keep input data from another model on failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm building a form to create `WorkOrders` that have a list of `Addresses`, and I need to create both models in the same form. The code is actually not mine, I'm modifying it since the form doesn't work as expected: When some validation fails, the controller does a `render :new` call but the part of the form that contain the `Address` doesn't keep its data. I'm guessing it's because the form is created via the `form_for` helper and uses the `WorkOrder` model, so when it tries to fetch the data from the `WorkOrder` object that the `create` action in the controller tried to save, the view can't fetch the data for an `Address` that is not saved anywhere. The problem is I don't know how to show the data from the new `Address` I'm trying to create in the form.

**Maybe my explanation was a bit confusing, so here's the tl;dr**: I need to create a `WorkOrder` and an `Address` associated with that `WorkOrder` in the same form (the `WorkOrder` object has many addresses), but when validation fails, the form doesn't show the `Address` data that was input.

The rest of the data (i.e. the data that come from columns of the `WorkOrder` model and don't belong to other model) shows up correctly.

The `show.html.erb` view renders a `_form.html.erb` partial that is like this (in this case, `work_order` is a local variable that comes from `show.html.erb` and contains `@work_order`):

```
<%= form_for(work_order, method: :post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :order_number, 'Order number' %>
  <%= f.text_field :order_number %>
  # ... other normal fields that are attributes of the WorkOrder model ...
  # these fields retain their info as expected, the problem is only with Address
  
  # These fields don't use helpers in the original code, so I'll just write them as they are
  # they are part of the Address model
  <label for="work_order_street">Street</label>
  <input id="work_order_street" type="text" name="work_order[address][street]">
  
  <label for="work_order_number">Number</label>
  <input id="work_order_number" type="text" name="work_order[address][number]">
  # etc...
  
  <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

And this is a short version of a very ugly `WorkOrdersController` code:

```
def new
    @work_order = WorkOrder.new
end

def create
  @work_order = WorkOrder.new(work_orders_params.except(:address))
  
  # Then there's a bunch of ugly logic which is not good
  # In short, I save the order twice (yikes). First, I create
  # a new Address and add it to @work_order.addresses and try
  # to calculate some things about the order and if everything goes well
  # I save the order again. The new address is created like this:
  @work_order.set_address(work_orders_params)
  
  # set_address returns true if it creates and adds a new Address to the @work_order object
  # at this point @work_order.addresses has the new Address created with set_address()
  
  respond_to do |format|
    if saved
        format.html { redirect_to work_order_path(@work_order, page: @page), notice: 'All good.' }
    else
        flash[:error] = add_flash_alert @work_order
        format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

private
def work_orders_params
    params.require(:work_order).permit(:order_number, ..., { address: [:street, :numeration, ...] })
end
```

And if I have a validation error, the form doesn't show the `Address` data I just entered and I have to write it again. How should I build the form so that it keeps that information? (considering @work_order has an array of addresses and not just one).

Comment: This contains a classic Ruby newbie misstake. You're assigning the instance variable `@work_order` and you're referencing `work_order` which is resolved to either a local variable or a method call. The code provided does not actually explain where `work_order` is defined but it definately is since you would get a NoMethodError otherwise.

Comment: @max the work_order variable is a local variable rendered by the `_form` partial. The variable comes from `show.html.erb` and it's @work_order. It does come from the new/create controller.